# Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using jsGantt chart. To fill chart I am using xml file.
**Problem is that xml file is outside project(root directory). so when jsgantt.js try to load xml file to fill chart it gives error like** 

[image]

jsGantt.js' code is below which throws error.

```
JSGantt.parseXML = function(ThisFile,pGanttVar){
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;   // Is this Chrome 

try { //Internet Explorer  
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    }
catch(e) {
    try { //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, Chrome etc. 
        if (is_chrome==false) {  xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null); }
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e.message);
        return;
    }
}

if (is_chrome==false) {     // can't use xmlDoc.load in chrome at the moment
    xmlDoc.async=false;     
    xmlDoc.load(ThisFile);      // we can use  loadxml
    JSGantt.AddXMLTask(pGanttVar);
    xmlDoc=null;            // a little tidying
    Task = null;
}
else {
    JSGantt.ChromeLoadXML(ThisFile,pGanttVar);  
    ta=null;    // a little tidying 
}
};
```

error in ***xmlDoc.load(ThisFile);*** line where argument ThisFile is file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, IIS isn't going to serve files outside the directory of the website. That would be a pretty big security hole.

You could try making the directory containing the file into another virtual directory, and allow anonymous access.

Or just move the file.

Comment: @SP: Thanks.. I have move the files.